# How to pass variable parameters to Observer?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I have two Observers that are merged with a flatMap. The first observer returns a value that is used when the second is called.

```
Observable<Integer> mergedObservers = firstAPI.getFirstInfo(userLat, userLong)
.flatMap(resultFirstObservable -> {
     try {
        return secondApi.getSecondInfo(resultFirstObservable.body().string(), "3") 
        .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
             return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
          });
      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3") 
        .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
             return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
          });
    });
}
}, (resultFirstObservable, resultSecondObservable) -> {
try {
    return transformToWhatINeed(resultSecondObservable.body().string());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return transformToWhatINeed([]);
}
});
```

userLat and userLong are declared outside my method and are changed during the time the activity is open, but my Subscription takes into account only the first value of these. I would have expected that each time there's a new call, they will take the newest values.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried using combineWithLatest?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones I looked into it for a few hours already and couldn't find a solution. I thought I should create an Observable for the location and on each call of subscribe, feed the first API with the location, but directly creating an Observable is deprecated.

Comment: I dont get how that wont work.. Observable.combineLatest(firstobservable, secondobservable, <your merger function>)

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question.. So to clarify you want that everytime your userLong ans userLat changes value.. You should get another value out of the stream.. Am I right?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones Yes. The user changes his position, and if the latitude and longitude changed on a second call of the Observable, the API should be called with the new position. If I put the variable like this, the Observable will make the call only with the first values of the parameters and not change them when they will change.

Comment: If you could post how the userLat, userLong are taken maybe I could help you more..

Comment: By taken i mean how their values are set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you problem correctly using Observable.defer should solve problem

```
Observable<Integer> mergedObservers = Observable.defer {
    firstAPI.getFirstInfo(userLat, userLong)
}.flatMap ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be like:

```
 Observable.combineLatest(userLatObservable, userLongObervable, yourmergerfunction).flatmap( lat, long –> firstApi.get(lat, long))... Etc..
```

I think you problem is that how do you get the value of userLat amd userLong... Those values should first be converted to Observables to join them in the chain.