# How to create a Observable from a LocationEngineProvider from MapBox?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, mapbox, mapbox-android

In my Activity, I initialize the localion engine:

```
    LocationEngineProvider locationEngineProvider = new LocationEngineProvider(this);
    locationEngine = locationEngineProvider.obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable();
    locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationEngine.activate();
```

In my Presenter, I want to pass the location variables to an API call which returns an Observable answer. The problem is that putting location values into the API call make it request the same parameters each time when I subscribe to this Observable. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893435/how-to-pass-variable-parameters-to-observer))

What I want to do, is to create an Observable that would get the Location and that would put the values into the first API parameters call.

```
Observable<Integer> mergedObservers = 
    *???ObservableForLocation()???*.flatMap(location -> 
         return firstAPI.getFirstInfo(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())
    .flatMap(resultFirstObservable -> {
     try {
        return secondApi.getSecondInfo(resultFirstObservable.body().string(), "3") 
        .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
             return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
          });
      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3") 
        .onErrorResumeNext(e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
             return secondApi.getSecondInfo("defaultValue", "3");
          });
    });
}
}, (resultFirstObservable, resultSecondObservable) -> {
try {
    return transformToWhatINeed(resultSecondObservable.body().string());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return transformToWhatINeed([]);
}
});
```

I would use some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: this is the third time you posted similar questions and since you didn't accept any of them I propose you to keep only one question, edit it by making it more clearer and remove all the others.

Comment: @Lino The three questions are three different things I was struggling with, thatțs why I divided it in 3, because I think it relates to different subhects. The first question actually helped me solve my first issue (thanks, @akarnokd), but I was waiting for him to edit his answer to help maybe some other people better when coming to that page, eitherway I accepted his question. The second question it's still open as I'm still figuring out how to do it, but the answers helped me go in the right direction, I will also accept one of it once I'm done with it.